# Codigo dentro de Opcion select

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Actual mente en mi boton Edit tengo un select , el que quiero que presente la opcion de mi tabla automaticamente, al momento lo estoy mostrando asi:

```
<select name="estado" class="form-control" value="{{$clientes->estado}}">

        @if($clientes->estado == 'Inactivo')
  <option value="Inactivo" selected="selected">Inactivo</option>
        @else
  <option value="Inactivo">Inactivo</option>
        @endif

        @if($clientes->estado == 'Confirmado')
  <option value="Confirmado" selected="selected">Confirmado</option>
        @else
  <option value="Confirmado">Confirmado</option>
        @endif

</select>
```

Mi intencion es colocar el codigo de blade dentro de la opcion para evitar tanto codigo y texto de la siguiente manera:

```
<option value="Inactivo" 

       @if ($clientes->estado == 'Inactivo') selected="selected" @andif

>Inactivo</option>
```

el problema es que la flecha -> me cierra el `<option` y quisiera hacerlo mas resumiedo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar un operador ternario:

```
<select name="estado" class="form-control">
    <option value="Inactivo" {{($clientes->estado == 'Inactivo')? ' selected': ''}}>Inactivo</option>
    // ...    
</select>
```

Comment: muchas gracias , al principio lo vi y note el cambio de color que interrumpia el imput pero al implementarlo funciona perfecto . gracias